# Common Table Expression to traverse down hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

## The Structure

I have 2 tables that link to each other. One is a set of values and a nullable foreign key that points to the Id of the other table, which contains *2* foreign keys back to the other table.

```
HierarchicalTable
Id    LeftId    RightId    SomeValue
1     1         2          some value
2     3         4          top level in tree
3     5         6          incorrect hierarchy 1
4     7         8          incorrect result top level

IntermediateTable
Id   SomeValue             HierarchicalTableId
1    some value            NULL
2    value                 NULL
3    NULL                  1
4    value                 NULL
5    incorrect result 1    NULL
6    incorrect result 3    NULL
7    incorrect result 3    NULL
8    NULL                  3
```

Each table points *down* the hierarchy. Here is this structure graphed out for the Hierarchical Table records 1 & 2 and their IntermediateTable values:

```
(H : HierarchicalTable, I : IntermediateTable)

                    H-2
                   /   \
                 I-3    I-4
               /     
             H-1 
           /    \
         I-1    I-2
```

## The Problem

I need to be able to send in an `Id` for a given HierarchicalTable and get all the HierarchicalTable records below it. So, for the structure above, if I pass 1 into a query, I should just get H-1 (and from that, I can load the related `IntermediateTable` values). If I pass 2, I should get H-2 and H-1 (and, again, use those to load the relevant `IntermediateTable` values).

## The Attempts

I've tried using a CTE, but there are a few main things that are different from the examples I've seen:

- In my structure, the objects point *down* to their children, instead of *up* to their parent
- I have the Id of the *top* object, not the Id of the *bottom* object.
- My hierarchy is split across 2 tables. This *shouldn't* be a big issue once I understand the algorithm to find the results I need, but this could be causing additional confusion for me.

If I run this query:

```
declare @TargetId bigint = 2
;
with test as (
    select h.*
    from dbo.hierarchicaltable h
    inner join dbo.intermediatetable i
    on (h.leftid = i.id or h.rightid = i.id)

    union all

    select h.*
    from dbo.hierarchicaltable h
    where h.id = @TargetId
)
select distinct *
from test
```

I get all 4 records in the `HierarchicalTable`, instead of just records 1 & 2. I'm not sure if what I want is possible to do with a CTE.

Comment: To begin, you don't have a where clause in the CTE above the union all statement so it will return any rows where there is a match on the intermediate table on either left or right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
I'm build entire tree with both tables, then filter (only hierarchicaltable records).

```
DECLARE @HierarchicalTable TABLE(
    Id          INT,
    LeftId      INT,
    RightId     INT,
    SomeValue   VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO @HierarchicalTable
VALUES                                                    
(1,     1,         2,          'some value                '),
(2,     3,         4,          'top level in tree         '),
(3,     5,         6,          'incorrect hierarchy 1     '),
(4,     7,         8,          'incorrect result top level')

DECLARE @IntermediateTable TABLE(
    Id                      INT,
    SomeValue               VARCHAR(MAX),
    HierarchicalTableId     INT
)
INSERT INTO @IntermediateTable
VALUES
(1,    'some value'            ,NULL  ),
(2,    'value '                ,NULL  ),
(3,    NULL                    ,1     ),
(4,    'value '                ,NULL  ),
(5,    'incorrect result 1'    ,NULL  ),
(6,    'incorrect result 3'    ,NULL  ),
(7,    'incorrect result 3'    ,NULL  ),
(8,    NULL                    ,3     )

DECLARE @TargetId INT = 2;

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Id AS ResultId, LeftId, RightId, NULL AS HierarchicalTableId
    FROM @HierarchicalTable         
    WHERE Id = @TargetId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C.Id AS ResultId, C.LeftId, C.RightId, NULL AS HierarchicalTableId 
    FROM @HierarchicalTable C
    INNER JOIN CTE          P ON P.HierarchicalTableId = C.Id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NULL AS ResultId, NULL AS LeftId, NULL AS RightId, C.HierarchicalTableId 
    FROM @IntermediateTable C
    INNER JOIN CTE          P ON P.LeftId = C.Id OR P.RightId = C.Id
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE ResultId IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I had to argue with SQL a little bit about `null`s and `bigint`s (and I ended up having to cast the nulls), but after that this worked great. Thanks!